# Get a playlist entry by ID with YouTube API (PHP)?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm currently in the middle of a project that involves YouTube API. I'm using the Zend Gdata, and everything has gone nicely until this.

I need to get a `Zend_Gdata_YouTube_PlaylistListEntry` based on the ID of the playlist. I have managed to retrieve the videos with some fiddling:

```
$feed = $yt->getVideoFeed('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/'.$id.'?v=2');
$playlist = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube_PlaylistListEntry($feed->getDOM());
```

However, I need to use the method `$playlist->getPlaylistVideoFeedUrl()`, and it returns `NULL` in this case.

Any help regarding this is appreciated =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it:

```
$url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/'.$input['id'].'?v=2';
$feed = $yt->getPlaylistVideoFeed($url);
```